# Flatpickr selecting months always triggering another flatpickr

Tags: flatpickr

I'm encountering an error when I use two flatpickr.

the html and code is as follows:

```js
$('#end_periode').flatpickr({
  dateFormat: "d-m-Y"
});

$('#start_periode').flatpickr({
  dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    $('#end_periode').flatpickr({
      dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
      minDate: dateStr,
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input id="start_periode" name="start_date" type="text" />
<input id="end_periode" name="end_date" type="text" />
```

whenever I clicked either previous month or next month on the end_periode, the start_periode always opened.

I tried to declare only start_periode but it's all the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit more? When i try to change the date of the `end_periode` its not opening `start_periode` picker.